# selenium xpath for the particular tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

what will be the Xpath for this input tag

```
"<input autocapitalize="sentences" autocorrect="off" class="css-1cwyjr8 r-19sur4y r-qklmqi r-1phboty r-1wdu9aa r-ubezar r-16dba41 r-10paoce r-12rqra3 r-13qz1uu" dir="auto" spellcheck="false" type="email" data-focusable="true" value="" style="font-family: inherit;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//input[@class='css-1cwyjr8 r-19sur4y r-qklmqi r-1phboty r-1wdu9aa r-ubezar r-16dba41 r-10paoce r-12rqra3 r-13qz1uu']
```

Or this:

```
//input[@type='email']
```

Answer (score 0):

if only element with @type=email, then can use `//input[@type='email']`

Comment: what are the attribute we can use ?

Comment: you can use any, but when you write your xPath, it should show 1 of 1 element found, because if there will be more, then your chosen element could be second and you won't be able to interact with it